# square moving only up and down, Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to learn tensorflow, so far its really simple but something has got me at a stand still. When I run my code, the cube only goes either down or right. I tried changing values and have concluded that the movement is what tensorflow has intended. I really don't know what to do here. I am lost!

the premise of what im trying to do is make an "AI" to learn its environment and go to all of the dots that randomly spawn.

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(2,), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

EPOCHS = 10

#somewhere in the while loop

inputs = np.array([square_x, square_y])

prediction = model.predict(inputs.reshape(1, 2))
print(prediction) # -> [ [x value, y value] ]
direction = np.argmax(prediction)


square_x += prediction[0][0]
square_y += prediction[0][1]
```

full code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pygame


pygame.init()


SCREEN_SIZE = (400, 400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("TensorFlow Dot Collector")
DOT_COLOR = (0, 0, 255)
SQUARE_COLOR = (255, 0, 0)
DOT_RADIUS = 10
NUM_DOTS = 10
SQUARE_SIZE = 30
square_x = SCREEN_SIZE[0] // 2
square_y = SCREEN_SIZE[1] // 2
game_loop = True
score = 0
speed = 5

dot_positions = np.random.randint(0, SCREEN_SIZE[0], (NUM_DOTS, 2))
old_dotpositions = dot_positions

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)


output_data = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
input_data = dot_positions[:output_data.shape[0]]

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(2,), activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='tanh')
])


model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

num_epochs = 10

model.fit(input_data, output_data, epochs=num_epochs)
while game_loop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_loop = False
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    for dot_position in dot_positions:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, DOT_COLOR, dot_position, DOT_RADIUS)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, SQUARE_COLOR, (square_x - SQUARE_SIZE // 2, square_y - SQUARE_SIZE // 2, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE))

    inputs = np.array([square_x, square_y])

    prediction = model.predict(inputs.reshape(1, 2))

    direction = np.argmax(prediction)
    print(direction)
    square_x += prediction[0][0] * speed
    square_y += prediction[0][1] * speed
    for dot_position in dot_positions:

        if np.linalg.norm(np.array([square_x, square_y]) - dot_position) < DOT_RADIUS + SQUARE_SIZE // 2:

            score += 5
            dot_positions = np.delete(dot_positions, np.argwhere(np.all(dot_positions == dot_position, axis=1)), axis=0)

    if square_x < 0 or square_y < 0 or square_x > SCREEN_SIZE[0] or square_y > SCREEN_SIZE[1]:
        square_x =200
        square_y = 200
        score -= 10
        model.optimizer.lr.assign(score)
        score = 0
        dot_positions = old_dotpositions


    score_text = font.render(f"Score: {score}", True, (0, 0, 0))

    screen.blit(score_text, (10, 10))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: please post code or [mre]

Comment: Your output layer has a 'softmax' activation. This kind of activation function converts computed outputs to probabilities (i.e. the sum of all the final values sums up to 1.) All output values will be positives. If you want to go up, you want to have 'prediction[0][1]' negative, which is not possible with this activation layer. I would suggest to try and change 'softmax' to 'tanh' for example. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function for more explanations.

Comment: @jeandemeusy this does allow it to move it in any direction, tho i feel like my model isnt learning anything.

Comment: @Alexander i just added all the code ig